# How to find out if regexp parsed string part contains another string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, linq

Say we have a list of strings `L`, a given string `S`. We have a regexp like `(\w+)\-(\w+)`  we want to get all `L` elements for which `S` matches `$1` of regexp. How to do such thing?

Comment: Assuming that `S` is `bar`, and one item of `L` is `foo-bar-baz` - would you want that to be a match or not?

Comment: Why not just make the regex `S + @"\-(\w+)"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
// sample data
string[] L = new string[] { "bar foo", "foo bar-zoo", "bar-", "zoo bar-foo" };
string S = "bar";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\w+)\-(\w+)");
string[] res = L.Where(l => { 
      Match m = regex.Match(l);
      if (m.Success) return m.Groups[1].Value == S;
      else return false;
    }).ToArray();
```

and get

```
foo bar-zoo
zoo bar-foo
```

An easier way that probably works out for you too is to include `S` in the regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(S + @"\-(\w+)");
string[] res = L.Where(l => regex.Match(l).Success).ToArray();
```